# Как в Joomla вставлять PHP-код в обычный HTML?

Tags: joomla, joomla3, virtuemart

Как в Joomla вставлять PHP-код в обычный HTML?
Нужно вставить его в HTML-модуль для дальнейшего использования в Virtuemart 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать замечательный компонент Sourceer от Regular Labs.
Отлично подойдет для Ваших нужд. 
Требуемый код вставить между `{source}{/source}`, все заработает.

Answer (score 1):

Для это есть специальный модуль - https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/flexi-custom-code/